# How to insert generated id into a results table

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query

```
SELECT q.pol_id
FROM quot q
    ,fgn_clm_hist fch
WHERE q.quot_id = fch.quot_id

UNION

SELECT q.pol_id
FROM tdb2wccu.quot q
WHERE q.nr_prr_ls_yr_cov IS NOT NULL
```

For every row in that result set, I want to create a new row in another table (call it table1) and update pol_id in the quot table (from the above result set) with the generated primary key from the inserted row in table1.

table1 has two columns.  id and timestamp.

I'm using db2 10.1.

I've tried numerous things and have been unsuccessful for quite a while.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to use `table1` for anything else, or do you simply need to generate incrementing ID values for pol_id? DB2 10.0 exists only on z/OS; is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes.  I'm planning on using table1 for other things.  We're using db2 v10.1 on linux.  Thanks.

Comment: May be you could show us some of the numerous things you tried and why they didn't work for you? That would help us help you. One potential problem is that `UNION` in your query eliminates duplicates, so you may end up having fewer generated IDs than `pol_id` values you need to update. What would you want to do then?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: create a new table for the result set of your query, which has an [identity column](http://www.dbtalks.com/uploadfile/dkverma87/identity-column-in-db2/) in it. Then, after running your query, update the `pol_id` field with the newly generated ID in your result table.

Alteratively, you can do it more manually by using the  the `ROW_NUMBER()` OLAP function, which I often found convenient for creating IDs. For this it is convenient to use a stored procedure which does the following:

1. get the maximum old id from `Table1` and write it into a variable `old_max_id`.
2. after generating the result set, write the row-numbers into the `table1`, maybe by something like

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY <primary-key> ORDER BY <whatever-you-want>)
           + OLD_MAX_ID
        , CURRENT TIMESTAMP
   FROM (<here comes your SQL query>)
   ```
3. Either write the result set into a table or return a cursor to it. Here you should either use the same `ROW_NUMBER` statement as above or directly use the ID from `Table1`.